# Cannot log-in to any user accounts

Tags: boot, grub2, login

Our IT department has experienced rather high turnover in recent months. We have one computer running only ubuntu, we believe it's to manage the phones but to be honest we're not sure. I can only access the root command line via the Grub recovery menu. I've tried resetting the passwords on all the accounts and unlocking them but have not been successful. I've even tried boot-repair which displays NVRAM locked. I can't log in to any accounts even ones that I've since added. I have also tried changing the ownership of .Xauthority and still nothing. I'm still only available to use root command line in Grub recovery menu. Any ideas would be of great help.

Comment: As root, can you `su` (switch user) to another account?

Comment: I can switch users

Comment: i used the passwd command to change passwords, i've tried passwd -u, and usermod -u, all of them displayed successful but when i go to login it says attempt failed. also can't

Comment: That’s a very strange narrative - due to staff turnover, you’ve got a computer that no one can access and you don’t know what it does. Might be completely legitimate but you’re basically asking us to tell you how to get into a computer you don’t have access to?

Comment: I guess I didn't look at it from outside perspective lol, but it's a small business only has two IT guys me and my manager. Our 3 previous IT guys have all left within the last 6 months. I'm primarily networking and security and my manager is more of a server/software guy. I've been tasked with getting into this computer to make sure there's nothing on it that we may need in the future. We actually plan to install windows on it and put it on our production floor if it proves to not be a pertinent. I do see now where that looks fishy

Comment: @Will OP has root access to the computer. No need for alarm bells, I would think.

Comment: Perhaps I'm too suspicious!

Comment: Perhaps the user accounts are locked? Have you tried `sudo usermod -U username`? Or maybe the user’s default shell is `/bin/false`?

Comment: @mpboden I was thinking it might be something along that line, or `/home` being read-only.

Comment: Googling "NVRAM Locked" brings up a host of issues that have to do with UEFI/BIOS settings, or even with resetting CMOS jumpers. Perhaps backing up the data and reinstalling would be a good idea.

Comment: @mpboden shell is /bin/bash

Comment: @jos i'm not sure how to know if /home is read only i'm not super proficient with Linux just better than everyone else here lol

Comment: Do `ls -l /` and look at the permissions of `home`. These should be `drwxr-xr-x`and `home` should be owned by root.

Comment: 755,  but i did notice something odd. 1 user (not root) owns bin-> usr/bin , lib-> usr/lib , lib32,62,x32 as well as sbin